# AF_UNIX socket behaviour on client side before the server calls accept()

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I am writing some code to abstract AF_UNIX client-server comms away from higher-level user code.

The server uses epoll to detect when the listening socket has an incoming connection to accept. This follows the usual `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, and `accept()` functions. I've omitted the epoll code for brevity.

```
int server_socket = -1;
server_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);

assert(server_socket != -1);

char* socket_path = "/tmp/test_sock";
struct sockaddr_un address;
memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(address.sun_path, socket_path, strlen(socket_path));

int res = bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));

assert(res == 0);

res = listen(server_socket, 20);

assert(res == 0);

int connection_socket = -1;
connection_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

assert(connection_socket != -1);
```

I then have a client which requests a connection using a `socket()` and `connect()` sequence.

```
int client_socket = -1;
client_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);

assert(client_socket != -1);

char* socket_path = "/tmp/test_sock";
struct sockaddr_un address;
memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(address.sun_path, socket_path, strlen(socket_path));

int res = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
```

To allow some flexibility in the startup order of both applications without blocking the client on connect, I'm kicking off a 2nd thread to loop over the functions above until the `connect()` call succeeds. At that point the client code then sets up another epoll in order to monitor the client-side socket for events.

This leads me to my questions:

1. `connect()` can succeed only after the server has called `listen()` on the bound socket. Before that it will either give an ENOENT or ECONNREFUSED. Is there a way to get connect() to only succeed after the server has called `accept()`? I've also monitored the client sockets via epoll and it can become writable even before `accept()` is called.
2. Can the client detect disconnects if the server is stopped after `listen()` is called but before `accept()` is called? `close()` on the listening socket doesn't produce an epoll event. Am I left to rely on the user code at the level above to attempt a hand shake and give up after a time has passed and the server has not responded?
3. Are there any differences in the above behaviours between abstract and pathname-bound sockets?

Comment: A passive listening socket behaves like a queue. The `listen` call is needed to set up this queue (the number is the size of the queue). When a client calls `connect` it's added to the queue of the listening socket. The `accept` call removes the next available connection from the queue. That's really all that `accept` actually is doing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought the answer to 1) would be no so thanks for the comment confirming that.